# Stack Level Too Deep - Ruby

Tags: ruby, stack-overflow, net-http

I have a stack overflow problem I can't seem to solve in a [ruby project](https://github.com/schatteleyn/Gimme-rate). In the file movie.rb, at the line 44-47, I call a function contained in the file mmc.rb.
When I test the file alone, mmc.rb works fine, but called several time in a loop, it causes a SO.

My stacktrace is in the following [Gist](https://gist.github.com/3930583).

I really don't understand why I got this.

Comment: do you really have to define methods inside another method?!

Comment: Good point, but even by defining mmc method at the line 12, and not around everything, I still have SO

Answer (score 1):

This is not a definitive answer but just 2 remarks:

First, there is no need or benefit for defining methods/functions within functions, your code just becomes unnecessarily complicated. Try to avoid this pattern if you can work around it (and in your case there is absolutely no need to have code like this).

Second: Your *Stack Level Too Deep* happens somewhere within the `Net::HTTP` module, so I quickly checked your code regarding `Net::HTTP` calls. You are using the `open` function from the *open-uri* library but you are not using it properly: whenever you open some stream for reading, you have to close it when you are done. You can achieve that using the following technique:

```
# sequential version -> you close the stream by yourself when
# you are done with it
stream = open('http://some.url/some/path')
data = stream.read
stream.close

# block version -> the open function closes the stream for you
# as soon as the passed block is evaluated.
data = open('http://some.url/some/path') {|stream| stream.read}
```

So you should replace all occurrences of `open(...).read` in your code with `open(...) {|s| s.read}`... This might as well fixes your stack level too deep, but I can't guarantee it. But as soon as you have refactored the code it will be easier to debug your problem...

Comment: I did refactor my code, but it didn't solve my problem. Thanks though